# What are the advantages of using FetchXml?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been asked this question in an interview, and since I didn't get to work so much with fetchXml (except for custom views in js), didn't know how to answer it.
So, what are the advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FetchXML is a MSCRM proprietary query language in simple. What are it's advantages over Query Expression would have been a better question, and I'm answering that. Let me know if it wasn't the intent.

Advantages in brief:
a. Fetch XML is xml based query language and can be quickly understood.
b. It can be formed from Advanced Find in MSCRM. 
c. You can check the query and the result right away with tools such as FetchXML tester (part of XRM tool box). 
d. Check online about the limitations of Fetch XML.
e. Here's a simple comparison between Fetch XML and Query Expression:
   https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/021a4ad2-066c-4ce8-8184-f8628d13277a/exact-difference-between-query-expression-and-fetchxml?forum=crmdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

FetchXml is the query language for SSRS reports on MS Dynamics OnLine/365.

FetchXml supports aggregates (sum, count etc.) and grouping of results.

FetchXml can be used for complex queries when querying in JavaScript.

When you can choose between QueryExpression queries and FetchXml, use the first; it has a small performance advantage.

Comment: Did you mean to say "use the later" and not "use the first"? Query expression is converted to fetch internally, it is just a sugar coated syntax to build fetchxml.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM: no, `QueryExpression` queries are not converted to FetchXml internally.

Comment: Henk, you are correct, linq queries are converted to query expressions, not fetch. I am was aware one of the query format gets converted to another, got them mixed up.